# Binding Service doesn't call onBind and onServiceConnected

Tags: java, android, service, media-player

So I'm building my MusicPlayer and so I create a service to manage everything. I call `ContextWrapper.bindService()` and this should call `onServiceConnected` and `onBind` right? But this isn't the case for me.

Please tell me if I got anything wrong there.

Here is my code:

This is my method to bind a Activity to the service (MusicUtils.java) . In my Activity it looks like this: MusicUtils.bindToService(this, this);

```
public static final ServiceToken bindToService(final Context context,
                                               final ServiceConnection callback) {
    Activity realActivity = ((Activity)context).getParent();
    if (realActivity == null) {
        realActivity = (Activity)context;
    }
    final ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(realActivity);
    contextWrapper.startService(new Intent(contextWrapper, MediaPlayerService.class));
    final ServiceBinder binder = new ServiceBinder(callback);
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(contextWrapper, MediaPlayerService.class);
    if (contextWrapper.bindService(intent, binder, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
        mConnectionMap.put(contextWrapper, binder);
        Log.e("MusicUtils","Bound");
        return new ServiceToken(contextWrapper);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my ServiceBinder:

```
public static final class ServiceBinder implements ServiceConnection {

    private final ServiceConnection mCallback;
    public ServiceBinder(final ServiceConnection callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(final ComponentName className, final IBinder service) {
        mService = IMusicSlideService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onServiceConnected(className, service);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(final ComponentName className) {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onServiceDisconnected(className);
        }
        mService = null;
    }
}
```

And this is my onBind(MediaPlayerService.java) :

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("Service", "onBind");
    return mBinder;
}
```

If you need something please tell me!

Thanks!!!

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing with `realActivity` and those references to `ContextWrapper`. Here is a sample application demonstrating the use of `bindService()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AdvServices/Binding

Comment: I saw this in another application and so I took it from there. Unfortunately it's still not working even with your implementation. Is it right that `onServiceConnected` and `onBind` are called when `bindSerivce`is called?

Comment: My implementation works. Run the app and put breakpoints in `onBind()` and `onServiceConnected()`. Both will be called. In general, they will be called if there are no problems (e.g., missing `<service>` element in manifest), and problems should show up as warnings or errors in LogCat.

Comment: No question that your code works but there has to be a problem in my app that this doesn't work. Now I know that `onBind` is called but `onServiceConnected` not. I got the `<service>` in the Manifest. I really can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I use code below and all works fine.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Connector.class);
mContext.bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

May be your problem is in using ContextWrapper?

Or try to change new Intent().setClass(contextWrapper, MediaPlayerService.class); to new Intent(contextWrapper, MediaPlayerService.class);

Comment: You do not need `startService()` to bind to a service.